# Uplodable stof doctrine extensions - The file "" does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions, doctrine-uploadable

### MY PROBLEM

I am tying to make `stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` work with `symfony3`. Therefore instead of using `$form->bind` as listed in example in stof documentation I tried `$form->handleRequest`. Unluckily after submitting the form I get the following error:

> The file "" does not exist

I would be thankful for you advise what am I doing wrong. Maybe somebody would be so kind and provide me with example of working upload scripts?

---

### MY CODE

---

My Controller code looks like this:

```
 public function plikAction(Request $request, $dok_id, $plik_id)
    { 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if($plik_id == "nowy") $plik = new plik();
        /.../
        $form = $this->createForm(plikType::class, $plik);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {
            if($plik_id == "nowy")
            {
                $em->persist($plik);
                $uploadableManager = $this->get('stof_doctrine_extensions.uploadable.manager');
                $uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload($plik, $plik->getName());
                $em->flush();
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success','Dodano plik ');
            }
            /.../
    }
```

form is build using the following function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('oznaczenie')
            ->add('name', FileType::class)
            ->add('wgraj', SubmitType::class);
    }
```

and my entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
  * @Gedmo\Uploadable
 */
class plik
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFileName
     */
    private $name;

    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFilePath
     */
     protected $path;
```

I am using default configuration as listed here https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the `Symfony3`  error:

> The file “” does not exist

was connected with PHP not being able write the file down to temporarily folder due to `open_basedir` restrictions.

Therefore in any case you see this error in Symfony3 make sure that correct permissions are set to folders and that PHP may write data into it.

Answer (score 1):

By default the value of `default_file_path` is `%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads`.

To make it working with the default configuration,
create the `uploads` folder in the `web` directory of your application:

```
mkdir web/uploads
```

And make it writable by setting up the correct permissions depending on your web server user.

Assuming `www-data` is the web server user, use the following:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data web/uploads
```

Or change the directory permissions using `chmod` (at your own risk):

```
chmod -R 755 web/uploads
```

(in case of this commands needs to be executed as root, prefix them with `sudo`)

Hope this solves your problem.